Transit Query for Indian Passport holder at Indian Airport
I am an Indian Passport holder.
I am coming from Sao Paulo to Mumbai on Qatar Airways and my layover is around 5 hours then I am travelling to Saudi Arabia on Kuwait Airways. I don't have check-in baggage. So, do I need to clear immigration or can I go for my next flight?

Where? Are all flights on the same ticket or have they been booked separately?

seperate ticket, GRU to BOM on QR and BOM to JED on KU

Not posting as an answer because I’m not sure, however as you don’t have checked luggage this indicates that you should be able to follow the international transit signs to stay airside for your next flight (you will need to clear Security AFAICT)

@MaqsoodKhan Out of curiosity, where did you book this itinerary? Flying GRU-DOH-BOM-KWI-JED on two separate tickets is kinda nuts.
